# exporting .sql in php

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

i want to export sql and excel file using php from daatabase. tried every thin found on here but not working.

see code it shows error "Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\dan\index.php 
There was a warning during the export of school to ~/one.sql"

```
<?php

$mysqlDatabaseName ='school';
$mysqlUserName ='root';
$mysqlPassword ='';
$mysqlHostName ='';
$mysqlExportPath ='one.sql';


$command='mysqldump --opt -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' > ~/' .$mysqlExportPath;
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
    case 0:
        echo 'Database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> successfully exported to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'There was a warning during the export of <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
        break;
    case 2:
        echo 'There was an error during export. Please check your values:<br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr></table>';
        break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Specify a full path to `mysqldump`
2. If a hostname and a password are empty don't specify corresponding options
3. Make sure that export path is writable

Try this

```php
$output = array();
$worked = 2;
$command = "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump --opt";
if (!empty($mysqlHostName))
    $command .= " -h$mysqlHostName";
$command .= " -u$mysqlUserName ";
if (!empty($mysqlPassword)) 
    $command .= " -p'$mysqlPassword'";
$command .= " $mysqlDatabaseName > /tmp/$mysqlExportPath";
// your code goes here
```

*Adjust paths to mysqldump and to export folder accordingly*